# Fadein and fadeout to a text inside canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The code I actually use:

[image: My code as an image]

Hello guys, I started using Javascript 2 days ago and I want to develop a game, so i thought the first step was making a "company name" intro using javascript. What my code actually do it execute a function that writes a text (the company name) inside the canvas, then delete it and write another text (which I want to replace with the game menu in the future instead of a text, this is just the first try to know if the code is working which it does). The problem is that i don't know how to fade in a simple text, I tried with jquery but I don't know how to "put an "id" to the first text (i don't even know if it's possible) so I can "fade in and out" that specific id.

I'd really appreciate any help, thanks in advance, Nicolás.

PS: it's the first time I'm using this platform so I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask a question

Comment: It's best if you post the actual code as text, instead of a screenshot. If appropriate, use a 3rd party site such as jsfiddle.net if you need to post separate HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Or just use the inline code snippet feature for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this several ways. If placed where you indicated in the picture, we can do a couple of small changes first:

[image: initial changes]

Here we first move out properties that can be set once and don't need to be updated inside the loop (remember to use a generic default/fallback font for `font` as not all systems has the "Arial" available).

Secondly: you need to add a condition for the `setTimeout()` as you don't want it to jump straight to `Numerito2()`, but wait until the animation has finished.

The animation itself will use a variable (`t`) to track current opacity for logo drawing, and a condition: when finished go to `Numerito2()`, if not continue to increase opacity.

And finally we use `requestAnimationFrame()` to animate as this syncs to the frame rate of the monitor.

The final code for the animation will look like this:

[image: Final animation code]

Which gives us this result (looped for demo):

[image: wrong anim]

Oops! Sorry, wrong code. Here's the result:

[image: Resulting animation]

> **Congratulation!** The troll has been defeated [image: troll]! You gain access to the [full code [image: potofgold]](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/636gpthe/)